# Повторная отправка запроса от CursorLoader

Tags: android

Добрый вечер, может ли кто- нибудь объяснить как после того как при помощи Content Provider вставил новые строки в базу данных, заставить CursorLoader произвести новый запрос?

Answer (score 0):

При вставке в методе вставки провайдера надо вызывать:

`getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)`

Это должно автоматически обновить `CursorLoader`